# How to use a receiver info at other activity or fragment, in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a receiver that will notify if and when the phone is connected to the Internet.

Now, the thing is that I have got a main activity that handles two fragments.
In one of the fragments, I have a search method that needs to use the Internet.
So, what I am trying to do is: if there's no Internet, then the user will get a toast, after he/she pressed the search button.

In order to do this - I've written the following class in the main activity -

```
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       Boolean netBol;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null
        && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    if (isConnected){

         Boolean netBol = true;

    }else{

        netBol = false;
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the Boolean netBol, to determine if there's a connection or not.

But the point is that i want to pass it to the search fragment, and I don't know how to do that.

I've also added the following line to the manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and I also put the following code in the main activity;

```
   ConnectionChangeReceiver netReceiver = new ConnectionChangeReceiver();
            IntentFilter filterNet = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");

            registerReceiver(netReceiver, filterNet);
```

For my understanding this is saying that I've declared on a receiver, but I need one at the fragment.

So what I'm asking is: what should I do in order to pass the info from the receiver to the fragment, so that I could know if there's internet or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple. Use [otto](http://square.github.com/otto/)

You will find the [sample application here](https://github.com/square/otto/tree/master/sample/src/main/java/com/squareup/otto/sample).

### Change your code as follows:

You can do something like this in your receiver:

```
if (isConnected){

BusProvider.getInstance().post(new InternetAvailable(true));

}else{

BusProvider.getInstance().post(new InternetAvailable(false));
Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

`InternetAvailable` class can be like this:

```
public class InternetAvailable {
  private static boolean isInternetAvalable;
  

  public InternetAvailable(boolean isInternetAvailableParam) {
  isInternetAvailable = isInternetAvailableParam
  }

  @Produce public InternetAvailable isInternetAvailable() {
    return isInternetAvailable;

  }
}
```

The `BusProvider` class is like this:

```
public final class BusProvider {
  private static final Bus BUS = new Bus();

  public static Bus getInstance() {
    return BUS;
  }

  private BusProvider() {
    // No instances.
  }
}
```

Modify your `SearchFragment` like this:

```
@Override public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
}

@Override public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i must say that i never heard of this. But i haver a question - is there no way to aplly a reciver in the fragment? let's say adding a ConnectionChangeReceiver instance in the fregmant, and trying to  retrive any info from the class of it?

Comment: Using otto you're doing the same thing, but if you want you can send intents to your own activity/fragment from the receiver and pass info about internet state.

Comment: @4this If you found this helpful, kindly upvote or accept answer.

Comment: So what should i do if i want to do it in the old fashion way, what should i add to the fregment? what info should the reciver send and what should the fregment will recive?

Comment: You can have a BroadcastReceiver as an inner class in your Fragment. Instantiate and attach it. Since Inner classes have access to outer class fields, update a field variable in the Fragment. That field will contain if internet is accessible or not.